# Jedi-vim automatically insert only matching option (need to disable it)

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, jedi-vim

Problem is when jedi-vim finds only one match for autocomplete it automatically insert this match. I need somehow disable this feature.

What I've already tried:

- `let g:jedi#smart_auto_mappings = 0`, but it only disables auto `from ... import ...` insertion;
- `let g:jedi#popup_on_dot = 0`, but it also disable popup on dot options (so I need to type `<C-space>` to see it).
- `let g:jedi#popup_select_first = 0` also won't help as it only disable first match selection in popup menu, but not prevent auto insertion of only match.

Also I don't have any other autocomplete plugins installed. If it helps, [this](https://github.com/valentjedi/vim_config/blob/master/.vimrc) is my .vimrc file

Is there some way to disable auto insert of only matching feature but keep popup on dot?

P.S. you can recreate this behavior with this example:

```
class A(InvisibleClass):
    i = 1
```

Then when you type `A` and press dot `i` will be inserted automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by Vim's [`completeopt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27completeopt%27) option.  jedi-vim sets it to `menuone,longest,preview` since you haven't changed it ([starting here](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/blob/master/plugin/jedi.vim#L16)).  You should explicitly set it in your `.vimrc` to include `noinsert`.

Vim's docs say that `noinsert` has no effect if `longest` is present, but that doesn't match the behavior I'm actually seeing (`NVIM 0.0.0-alpha+201510011522 (compiled Oct  5 2015 14:55:04)`).

Comment: Oh man I wish if I could give you more then one upvote, it was so helpful! I just put `set completeopt=menuone,longest,preview,noinsert` in my .vimrc and that solved all my troubles.